# How to load asp:Content into a subpage in ASPX

Tags: html, asp.net, master-pages

I have a master page where I am calling another sub-page using the 
`<asp:Content></asp:Content>`

- Default.aspx + master = Homepage
- why_choose.aspx + master = Subpage

Inside the Subpage I have a menu which other Subpages will also share, so instead of adding  the menu in each Subpage, is there any way I can add a `<asp:Content></asp:Content>` within the Subpage itself to load the menu?

If so, how do I do that?

Comment: when you create the content page, it should ask you what master page you want it to use. then by default it should pull all of your content place holders from the master page into your content page. you shouldn't have to do anything special

Comment: Yes the master pages is already doing that. I have different content inside Default.aspx and why_choose.aspx. The question is what if inside the why_choose.aspx I want to load some other content, how do I do that? So it will be menu_content > why_choose > master = second page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe you are misinterpreting master pages.

For your described scenario, your master page, generally `Site.master` should contain your menu markup.

Now, any pages you create (Default.aspx, why_choose.aspx) and use your `Site.master` page will also include your menu, although the markup is not visible within these sub pages.

If you want to load some other content into these sub pages, you simply put that new content into the `asp:contentplaceholder` on the sub pages.

Read up some more on master pages [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.ASPX#HowMasterPagesWork)

Answer (score 0):

try using an iframe element and loading your additional content in it.

[iframe on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)